# Eigen Library: Take a copy of a templated function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

Im trying to convert the content of an arbitrary Eigen-Vector/Array type to an std::array. I read this part from the Eigen doc http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html so this is my function:

```
template<typename DERIVED>
std::array<typename Eigen::DenseBase<DERIVED>::Scalar, Eigen::DenseBase<DERIVED>::RowsAtCompileTime>
toStl (const Eigen::DenseBase<DERIVED>& input)
{
... // Do conversion
}
```

The issue is now, that when I remove the ampersand from the *input* parameter type in order to take a copy, I get an empty *input* variable. It contains some bogus value for coefficient 0 and the rest is zeroes.

When I take the parameter by reference, everything works fine. Can anybody tell me why?

PS.: For those who might wonder why I want to take a copy; Is it suggested in this talk in order to help the optimizer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14 (second half to end)

Comment: It seems that `Eigen::DenseBase<T>` has its copy constructor private, so it's not at all clear how did you manage to compile this without the ampersand.

Comment: Actually, `template<typename **OtherDerived**> explicit DenseBase(const DenseBase<**OtherDerived**>&)` is private. So it looks like the copy constructor to for the _same_ type (`Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`) exists - even though it I could not find a declaration - but uses the default definition. Since the class is empty, nothing is copied, which explains my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DenseBase<> class is an empty base class, so it does not make sense to create an object of that type. So if you really want to pass input by value, then its type must be DERIVED not DenseBase. Nevertheless, it still sounds weird to pass it by value while the only purpose of your function to make another copy.

Comment: I want to stress the points in this answer too. If you pass `DenseBase<>` by value, you circumvent the polymorphism and really get just a `DenseBase`. It's called *splicing*. So passing by value with the signature you have above is out. Also, it doesn't help the performance of your program *at all*, since you will have copied your data twice, instead of just once. I haven't watched the video, but I bet it talks about *pointer aliasing* which I don't think applies here (references of different types and not pointers, etc., etc.)

Comment: This intrigued me, so I benchmarked it and the version with the copy seems to be about as fast as - if not slightly faster - than the one with the reference. Even for vectors with 30 elements and more (usual number for me is trhee). I tested gcc 4.7 and clang 3.3 and both essentialy performed equally well.